# Which error to check for first, or do I code to check for all errors?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

I am running a weather sensor (BMP280) with a RaspberryPiZero2 located close to my home moth traps as part of a study into determine how/if seasonal/nightly species emergence correlates to outside temperature through the course of the year etc.  A Python program runs on the Pi, connects to my home WiFi, then at predetermined intervals uploads the data to Adafruit.io.  Simple really and all works pretty well except for an issue where every now and then I get connection errors.  So, sometimes in the morning when I check the overnight readings the code has stopped running and I thus don't gain that nights readings.  That hopefully explains the how and what of what I am doing.

The errors I receive from the code, in summary are:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

which leads to another similar error...

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [Err no-3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

which then leads to ...

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))ailed to establish a new connection: [Err no-3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

which ultimately leads to

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
 Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have already amended the /etc/resolv.conf file to append the nameserver 8.8.8.8 to the file which I was advised to do by a tech on the adafruit support forums.  However, I want to write a try-except section to cater for these errors, because whatever it  that's causing this error to occur simply goes away after an amount of time and as soon as I return to the terminal I am able to relaunch the app and voila, all works well.

So just in case this happens again I would like to check for an error with a try-except loop, but which error should I check for specifically? Once checked, if an error has occurred instead of the code stopping I can capture the error, wait for 30 mins, then reattempt to connect to the WiFi.  At least doing this will ensure I can get readings through the main part of any time period I am away from being able to monitor the Pi.

Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: In the general case, there is no way to prescribe a single solution. Often, catching the first error will prevent all of the other ripple-on errors, but it's also possible that there are multiple failure scenarios at different times, and you'll have to discover and catch them all.

Comment: This particular scenario looks like you just have to cope with the network losing connectivity every once in a while.

Comment: To troubleshoot, try unplugging the network cable from the unit physically, bringing down the network interface from the unit's command line, etc. If possible, also set up a DNS resolver of your own and have it accept connections but not send back responses, etc.

Comment: There is no sane way to enumerate "all errors". From your (vague) system description, the other obvious thing which can go wrong is that you somehow can't save your data permanently because the disk is full, your OS remounts the disk read-only because of hard disk corruption, or the other system where you upload results stops responding, etc.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice, folks.  Much appreciated.  I know very little about exception handling, but will have a little explore and see how I get on.  Anything I can do to mitigate the loss of missed readings will help.  Cheers.